# How do you reference a method from an object in a vector, if you don't know what class the object is from in Java?

Tags: java, object, methods, vector

I have a series of Objects in my prgram that I want to be held in a Vector as shown below:

```
public class Submarine{ //class that describes submarines

//...some code

int x, y;   

    public Submarine(){

        x = 10; 
    y = 93;

}

    public int getX(){
    return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
    return y;
    }

    //...some code

}



public class Dog extends animal{ //class that describes dogs

//...some code

    public Dog(){

        x = 12; 
        y = 54;

    }

    public String getBark(){

    return"Bark!"
    }

    public int getX(){
    return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
    return y;
    }

    //...some code

}


public class Cat extends animal{ //class that describes cats

//...some code

    public Cat(){

    x = 25; 
    y = 532;

    }

    public String getMeow(){

    return"Meow!"
    }

    public int getX(){
    return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
    return y;
    }

    //...some code

}


public class animal { // the superclass of the animals Dogs and Cats

//some code

    int x, y; // the x and y coordinates of the animal

//some code

}
```

In my main class, I also have a Vector that I want to hold these objects in:

```
import java.util.Vector;


public class MainClass { //the main class that runs the program

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Cat c = new Cat();
        Submarine s = new Submarine();
        Dog d = new Dog();

        Vector<Object> v = new Vector<Object>(); //Vector that holds random objects

        v.add(c);
        v.add(s);
        v.add(d);

}

}
```

Now I want to be able to reference the methods from each object, so i tried to put the following code into the end of my MainClass:

```
System.out.println(v.get(1).getMeow()); //should print "Meow!"
System.out.println(v.get(2).getBark()); //Should print "Bark!"
System.out.ptintln(v.get(3).getX()); //should print 10 from the submarine object
```

and even:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
System.out.println("X coordinate: " +v.get(i).getX + ", Y coordinate: " + v.get(i).getY);
}
```

But instead it throws a wobbly on me, and shouts an exception. How do i put objects into a Vector(objects that are not related in any kind of way) and reference the methods inside of each class without knowing the object's class that I am referencing? - that is my main question!

I was hoping that:
    v.get(index).whateverMethodIWant();
would work, but instead it wants to know what class I am calling the methods from, how do I get around this?

Comment: If you do not tell the Java compiler what the vector holds, you will need to use reflection to do this.

Comment: You can't really do that. It doesn't look like an appropriate place to use a Vector. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have made a game, and have a series of objects for different enemies, and so I want each of the enemies to be able to print thier images to the JFrame using a for Loop

Comment: Yeah, i guess reflection should work

Comment: Define an `interface` that defines a common action or actions that these "enemies" might perform. Have your enemy classes implement this interface (maybe it defines `doAction()` or something similar). Then in each class, wrap the appropriate class-specific method in the `doAction()` method. Change the vector to hold your interface type and you can simply call `v.get(0).doAction()`

Comment: Reflection should not be needed.  What are you trying to do?  What is a "wobbly" and what exception does it "shout?"  Details are important, you're never going to get a decent answer (or learn anything) if you don't ask a decent question.

Comment: The code `v.get(1).getMeow()` suggests you know `v.get(1)` is a `Cat`. If you know it's a `Cat` you can just cast it to a `Cat` like this `((Cat) v.get(1)).getMeow()`. If you don't know `v.get(1)` is a `Cat` you can use `v.get(1) instanceof Cat` to find out. But don't do this and certainly don't use reflection. Do what Ryan just said.

Comment: Ok, ill try what Ryan says, thanks guys

Comment: This code cannot possibly throw (shout?) an exception, since it won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want as you have it coded, reflection will certainly be your best (but not wisest) option. The example you've provided uses method names of objects that suggest you already know what types they are, as pointed out in the comments of the OP.

The idea behind object polymorphism is that you can define and invoke the different behavior of your objects without knowing their type at compile time.

The more common and perhaps "proper" way to do what you want is to define an interface or an abstract base class that describes the family of objects you're trying to store in your vector.

This interface will define and expose a set of common methods/operations that you can invoke on any object implementing that interface, who's specific implementation is determined by the implementing class.

For example, suppose you define an interface `Enemy` and it defines one method `getAction()`

```
public interface Enemy {
    public void getAction();
}
```

You can have your "enemy" classes, (we'll use your example of Dog, Cat, and Submarine) implement this interface, and wrap the specific function in the `getAction` method.

```
public Cat extends Animal implements Enemy {
    //....
    public void getAction() {
        getMeow();  // call cat's specific action
    }
}

public Dog extends Animal implements Enemy {
    //....
    public void getAction() {
        getBark();  // call dogs's specific action
    }
}

public Submarine implements Enemy {
    // ....
    public void getAction() {
        // for sake of argument, let's just getX();
        getX();
    }
}
```

Then, you can create a `Vector` of `Enemy` types, and simply call `getAction()` on them, without actually knowing the type.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Cat c = new Cat();
    Submarine s = new Submarine();
    Dog d = new Dog();

    List<Enemy> v = new Vector<>(); //Vector that holds random Enemy objects

    v.add(c);
    v.add(s);
    v.add(d);

    System.out.println(v.get(0).getAction()); //should print "Meow!"
    System.out.println(v.get(1).getAction()); //should print 10 from the submarine object
    System.out.ptintln(v.get(2).getAction()); //should print "Bark!"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared v to be a Vector of Object. The Object class does not have getX or getY methods which is why the compiler is giving you an error.

If you want to use getX and getY methods on the elements of v then you need to declare it as storing objects that have those methods. The way to do this is using an interface:

```
public interface Coordinated {
    int getX();
    int getY();
}

public class Submarine implements Coordinated {
    ....
}

List<Coordinated> v = new Vector<>();
v.add(new Submarine(...));
v.get(1).getX();
```